# How is the cross communication naming structure between two NEAR protocol smart contracts determined?

Tags: rust, blockchain, nearprotocol

When communicating between two NEAR protocol smart contracts. How is contract A accessed by contract B?

This question [How to call different contract from its address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879405/how-to-call-different-contract-from-its-address/63888134#63888134) covers this but doesn't specify how the naming structure is determined.

Using this example from https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/cd221798a77d646d5f1200910d45326d11951732/lockup/src/lib.rs#L64-L67

```
#[ext_contract(ext_whitelist)]
pub trait ExtStakingPoolWhitelist {
    fn is_whitelisted(&self, staking_pool_account_id: AccountId) -> bool;
}
```

Is the contract above ext_whitelist deployed as ext_whitelist.near? Searching the [near explorer](https://explorer.near.org/) There does not appear to be an account ext_whitelist.near

How would another contract with a different namespace be identified?

eg would  `contract1.contracts.near` be identified like `#[ext_contract(contract1.contracts)]` from any .near address and `#[ext_contract(contract1)]` from the `contracts.near` address?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly.

But Rust macro input on created the Rust object (pardon if I use incorrect terminology here) to communicate with the contract. You can re-use the same `ext_whitelist` object across multiple contracts.

The actual address of the contract is passed when you make a contract call:

```rust
            ext_status_message::get_status(
                env::signer_account_id(),
                &account_id,
                0,
                SINGLE_CALL_GAS,
            ),
```

The last three arguments are

- Contract address is account_id
- 0 - I have no idea
- Allocated gas

This is not very elegant design choice, as it is very confusing to read and use. I would suggest creating `Contract` instances like in other blockchains, instead of explicitly passing the contract address to every contract call.

Comment: - 0 is attached deposit.